# Shamsi date in power bi

Tags: sql, data-binding, powerbi, powerquery

how to write this command in power bi?

```
format('fire Fires'[Acceptance Letter Date]؛"dd/MM/yyyy"؛"fa")
```

I want to change a Gregorian date to a Shamsi date? This command is correct in sql server but it doesn't work in power bi.

Comment: Both `Miladi` and `Shamsi` calendars are **solar** calendars, am I wrong ? Can you please articulate well in English what you wanted to mean ?

Answer (score 0):

If your local culture is set to fa-IR, I believe you should just be able to do something like this in powerquery

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"PriorStepNameHere",{{"ColumnNameHere", type date}} , "en-US")
```